# Get Item from a table in Dynamodb AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to get_item from a table in dynamodb.

```
def read_table_item(table_name, pk_name, pk_value):
"""
Return item read by primary key.
"""
table = dynamodb.Table(table_name)
response = table.get_item( Key={pk_name: pk_value})

return response
```

print (read_table_item(table_name,pk_name="_id",pk_value={"S":str(1)}))

The error I get is

"botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the GetItem operation: The provided key element does not match the schema"

It will be helpful if somebody review the above piece and help us rectify the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me what ever you are passing to `pk_name` is not in the DynamodbSchema. See following for more informaton.

[Incorrect dynamo db key mapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/troubleshooting-and-common-mistakes.html#incorrect-dynamodb-key-mapping)